# Render shadow lines problem

Tags: rendering, shadows

Hi there well I'm kind of newish to Blender and my problem is when I do the Rendering I get some ,,shadow lines'' you can see them if you zoom in at the head, how can I avoid them or what did I do wrong in the settings.

Thanks for the help :P[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: “Shadow lines” its more the color linea which are in my concern I hope you understand me well if not you can ask

Comment: Sorry not following you. Which colour/shadow lines? can you highlight the areas in an extra image?

Comment: your picture is very dark, yes it looks like you have some waves on his head? please share your file or show a screenshot of the mesh, etc...

Comment: @rob I highlighted the area with the green color

Comment: @moonboots there are the settings I used to do the render. or how can I share the file

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I tried but the file size is about 50MB and its at max 30 allowed

Comment: you could cut out some of the textures or just remove the bottom half of the bear to make the file smaller.

Comment: Thx guys here we go :P Actually I might need to tell, I have a Geforce GTX 2080 and first I had a Kernel issue after I searched in youtube and downloaded the needed extra files.

Comment: its more about, are the files I downloaded causing the problem or is it in the settings I did something wrong?

Comment: I deleted the downloaded drivers and tried to render just with the cpu and the lines are still there my conclusion is that it has something to do with the settings. Could you figure it out?

Comment: So here is the new Blend file to download with a low poly so you can see the whole with the settings i tried renderd with cpu

Comment: Can't say much about lines, but mesh isn't dense enough to keep smooth shading transitions between triangles. As for problem inside circles - this is artifacts of Denoiser. Try to increase Radius or bump up render samples.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to Serge L I could figure out with different tries of the denoiser size and the amount of samples to get rid of the artifacts, the shadow/color lines could have been caused of the to dark scene so they mostly disappeared with more or brighter light, now Im happy with the result and can go on thx for the help guys.
[image]